# Fetching reminders in background using EventKit

Tags: ios, watchkit, eventkit

I am creating an Apple Watch app which has a button that makes a call to the parent iOS app.

```
WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(message, reply: {
            (response: [NSObject:AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in
    // processing data from iOS app
})
```

The iOS app responds by retrieving some reminders using EventKit, like so:

```
eventStore.fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate(predicate, completion: {
                [unowned self] reminders in
    // sending back data as reply to Apply Watch
})
```

When the parent app is in the foreground, everything works like a charm. But when I make the app go to the background, something strange happens. The call to EKEventStore, `eventStore.fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate(predicate)`, never calls my completion block. So I never send a reply back to the Apple Watch because of that?

So what is going wrong? I suspect a bug in EventKit, or maybe calling EventKit in the background is not supported. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Before letting `EKEventStore` spawn an async process, I have to start a background task. When I complete the async call, I have to explicitly end the background task.

```
// First let iOS know you're starting a background task
let taskIdentifier = application.beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler() {
    () -> Void in
    // Do something when task is taking too long
}
// Then do the async call to EKEventStore
eventStore.fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate(predicate, completion: {
            [unowned self] reminders in
    // Do what I have to do, and afterwards end the background task:
    application.endBackgroundTask(taskIdentifier)
})
```